# need to know margin size in mm

Tags: adobe-indesign

I am designing an outdoor pvc banner for a customer, ya know the ones that you tie to railings. Does anybody know what the standard size is for the inside margin for the text all the way round the banner?? in mm please? i am working with InDesign by the way

Answer (score 2):

All vendors are different. Contact the vendor who will be producing the banner and ask about their file submission requirements.